# JScriptEvaluator threw exception - Tridion 2009

Tags: publishing, 2009, xslt-mediator

The past couple of days, we've been getting this error quite randomly on our production environment:

```
The type initializer for 'Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Expression.JScriptEvaluator' threw an exception.
```

Like I said, it seems to happen randomly, with different type of components and/or pages and independent of target. I cannot reproduce it on another environment or by previewing the items.
I'm thinking of contacting CS, but thought I might as well try here first...

Comment: That error means that at run-time your Template is not semantically correct. Can you share more details about your templates?

Comment: We use compound templating for most pages (at least the ones I see in the failed items) together with an XSLT mediator. The strange thing is that I can succesfully publish them at this moment, it seems like a temporary hick-up...